# Linq query group by distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query which is almost complete.
It's working but I need to retrieve the original list of the items in the list that fulfills the requirements.

Now it only returns true or false if any has the `count > numberOfResourceToBook`.

But instead I want to return all the items in `availableTimes` having that (with all its properties).

```
bool enoughResourceAvailable = availableTimes.GroupBy(l => new { l.From, l.To })
  .Select(g => new
  {
      Date = g.Key,
      Count = g.Select(l => l.ResourceId).Distinct().Count()
  }).Where(c => c.Count  >= numberOfResourcesToBook).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: Well it sounds like you want `Entries = g.Where(l => l.ResourceId).Distinct()` in your anonymous type, or something like that... If that's *not* what you want, please provide a [mcve], because your description really isn't clear.

Comment: The first step is to look at the very last LINQ query you call. As you can see, yours is `.Count() > 0`, which is a statement which returns a Boolean, hence why you're getting an `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Comment: For what is the final `Count() > 0` needed?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, yes the .Count > 0 is needed as i only want those resources having rows. Even if i remove the Coun > 0 i will get the grouped result back. I want the element from availableTimes list with the statements in the where.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question and hopefully you already figured this out long ago.  But for someone else stumbling into this question, here is how you could solve it:

First, you need to add the available times for each group to the anonymous objects you are selecting so you have a way to get them back after grouping.  Get rid of the `.Count > 0` at the end so the result is an IEnumerable of the anonymous objects instead of a boolean.

```
var result = availableTimes
    .GroupBy(l => new { l.From, l.To })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Date = g.Key,
        Count = g.Select(l => l.ResourceId).Distinct().Count(),
        Times = g.Select(l => l)     // Add this to capture the times for the group
    })
    .Where(c => c.Count >= numberOfResourcesToBook);
```

Next, you can set the `enoughResourceAvailable` by using `.Any()` on the previous result.  It does the same job as `.Count() > 0` except it doesn't always need to enumerate the entire list: it can return true as soon as it finds at least one item.

```
bool enoughResourceAvailable = result.Any();
```

Lastly, to get all the times back which matched the query (if there are any), you can use `SelectMany()` on the result, like so:

```
var allMatchingTimes = result.SelectMany(c => c.Times);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HCEuMR

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!!